# Linux "alias" command question

Tags: bash, alias

Where any aliased command is stored? If I am aliasing "ls" as "l" then where will that aliased be stored? Does it affect .bashrc or .cshrc?

Comment: Related: [Where are shell functions stored on Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/858261/354511)

Answer (score 2):

There is no persistence for aliased commands - so if you 'alias l ls' and then exit bash, the alias is lost.

If you want them to persist, put them in ~/.bashrc

Comment: The alias is lost because it’s stored in memory for the shell process. Making them *persist*, as wef points out, means that a shell process reads a configuration file at startup to store desired configurations in memory.